# strange result from yield from in python

Tags: python, yield-from

I have a depth-first search example code in python as below.

```
def DFS_paths_recursive(self, start, end, path = None):
    if path == None:
        path = [start]
    if start == end:
        yield path
    else:
        unvisited = set(self._graph_dic[start]) - set(path)
        for vertex in unvisited:
            yield from self.DFS_paths_recursive(vertex, end, path+[vertex])
```

But if I modify the code as below, the output is strange. What I did is just modifying the path before the recursive call in the last line. What is the problem?

```
def DFS_paths_recursive(self, start, end, path = None):
    if path == None:
        path = [start]
    if start == end:
        yield path
    else:
        unvisited = set(self._graph_dic[start]) - set(path)
        for vertex in unvisited:
            path.append(vertex)
            yield from self.DFS_paths_recursive(vertex, end, path)
```

For example, for the graph `g = { "a" : ["d"], "b" : ["c"], "c" : ["b", "c", "d", "e"], "d" : ["a", "c", "e"], "e" : ["c"], "f" : ["g"], "g" : ["f"] }`
Sometimes the output of paths between "a" and "e" is `['a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'e'],['a', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'e']`, and sometimes the output becomes `['a', 'd', 'e']`.

Comment: "But if I modify the code as below, the output is strange." - "strange" isn't a useful error description. Please provide more detail, perhaps including actual program output.

Comment: Yield might not do what you expect. Have you seen this page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with `yield from`. When you do `path.append(vertex)`, you mutate the original copy of `path` (which means the version your caller passed you, and the version you pass to the recursive call). Even within the function, it's behaving differently, since repeated `append`s mean each recursive call is handling all the same values as the last plus one more, instead of a fixed base `path` plus a single additional value on each loop.

Doing `path+[vertex]` is creating a new `list` to pass to the recursive call, preventing mutations from affecting your own copy of `path`, and only adding one new `value` to the base `path` for each recursive call without changing the base `path`.